# Why I got such error message when trying to create a ttl index in azure cosmosdb?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, ttl, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, spatial-index

I'm trying to create some TTL indexes in azure cosmosdb collections (mongo API), these collection's elements are all string or integer, but when I use the index spec

```
{
 "expireAfterSeconds":1000,
 "key": {"_ts":1}
 }
```

to create TTL indexes, some collections can be created correctly, but some tables return such error message: "{"Errors":["Fields in 'spatialIndexes' are only allowed with newer API versions. Update your API version from '2018-06-18' to '2018-09-17' leverage this new feature."

but I do nothing about spatialIndexes, so why I got this error?

Comment: The cosmosdb version is 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something upgraded the index. Upgrading to 3.6 or 4.0 should solve the issue.

Comment: I'm curious about why other collections in the same DB can be created correctly

Comment: Not sure, need to see the activity logs if something was created already on this collection. You may create a support request